# function is creating large spaces when alert through jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, function, whitespace

I have a function which deals with sessions and cookies.

**functions.php**

```
function getUser()
{
     if(isset($_COOKIE["auth"]))
     {
         /* check cookie */
         echo $_COOKIE['auth'];
     }else if(isset($_SESSION["auth"])){
         echo $_SESSION["user_auth"];
     }
}
```

I also have a form and there's an alert associated with it. I have an ajax that when user submits the form, alert the function.

Everything works, but the only issue is that the alert pops up with lots of spaces in it. I've tried to use

```
trim(getUser);
```

and
    str_replace("","",getUser());

And this is causing me problems because I'm trying to input the session value or cookie value into mysql database. When I check if there's any values inside my mysql database, its just empty, and its not NULL.

Thanks!

AJAX:

**form.php**

```
$(".inputSubmit").submit(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var inputs= $('.inputForm').serialize();
      $.ajax({
           url: "submit.php",
           type: "POST",
           data: input,
           error: function(data){
                 alert(data.responseText);  
                 alert(data.responseStatus);
                 alert(data);
           }
      }).done(function(data){
           alert(data);
      });
});
```

**submit.php**

```
require "functions.php";

$users = str_replace("","",getUser());
echo $users;
```

lets say i have the alert box:

```
--------------------------------------
|                                    |
|                                    |
|                                    |
|                                    |
|                                    |
|  1                                 |
|                                    |
|                                    |
|                           OK       |
--------------------------------------
```

the 1 is the session output. the okay is the ok button when alert is popped out. Usually the 1 should be higher and smaller alert box, but its expanded as if there's white space.

Comment: more details in code, like how you did in your ajax part and returning.

Comment: Can you provide the output with the spaces? It could be useful! :)

Comment: try adding  -- `dataType: "text"` -- to $.ajax

Comment: @Dagon, that didn't change anything. its still giving large spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `return`, not `echo`.

```
function getUser()
{
     if(isset($_COOKIE["auth"]))
     {
         /* check cookie */
         return $_COOKIE['auth'];
     }else if(isset($_SESSION["auth"])){
         return $_SESSION["user_auth"];
     }
     return "";
}
```

Comment: ahhhh I was able to input it into mysql. but it still looks like there's spaces. oh well, as long as its getting into mysql. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

xdazz is right - you should have "return" and not echo. But that's probably not the problem. It is a problem though, and needs fixing. But I don;t see how it will cure your spaces problem.

The most likely reason is that you have the php opening tag:

```
<?php
```

or

```
<?
```

not at the top of your PHP pages, or you have the closing tag (?>) not at the bottom of your php file - or followed by empty characters.

For best practice, have the php opening tag at the very top, first line only, and ?> at the bottom, very last line with no "newline" after it. (You can also omit the ?> if you like, it's not required.) Anything outside those tags, including blank lines, will be echoed out and will push your display down.

Answer (score 0):

You may try `jQuery.trim()` OR `j$.trim(str)` OR a regex like `string.replace()` as well.

***[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/2veEY/)*** you can see all three methods. Choose the one right for you.